# Geoserver - PostGIS : WFS-Transaction update exception error-Parsing failed for Point:

Tags: postgis, geoserver, gml, geoserver-rest-api

I tried to perform a transaction update, but it failed with this exception message:

```
    <owsExceptionReport.xsd">
   <ows:Exception exceptionCode="NoApplicableCode"> 
    <ows:ExceptionText>java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for 
    Point: com.vividsolutions.jts.util.AssertionFailedException
    Parsing failed for Point: 
 com.vividsolutions.jts.util.AssertionFailedException
</ows:ExceptionText>
</ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Here's the update request sent:

```
   <wfs:Transaction  
    service="WFS" 
    version="1.1.0"  
    xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" 
  xmlns:SDSDupdate="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/SDSDupdate" 
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"  
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"  
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs  
                                            http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">  
                        <wfs:Update typeName="SDSDupdate:points">  
                          <wfs:Property>  
                            <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>  
                            <wfs:Value>  
                              <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">  
                                <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">15.453680224345835, 74.25796508789062</gml:coordinates>  
                              </gml:Point>  
                            </wfs:Value>  
                          </wfs:Property>  
                          <ogc:Filter>  
                            <PropertyIsEqualTo>  
                              <PropertyName>pid</PropertyName>  
                              <Literal>cd607b28-6ac5-85d1-bbb1-c880efbce4d9</Literal>  
                            </PropertyIsEqualTo>  
                          </ogc:Filter>  
                        </wfs:Update>  
                      </wfs:Transaction>
```

Is it the problem with PostGIS schema or with GML point coordinates being sent?

EDIT: Error performing insert: Error inserting features

```
   <wfs:Transaction  
    service="WFS" 
    version="1.1.0"  
    xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" 
  xmlns:SDSDupdate="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/SDSDupdate" 
    xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"  
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"  
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs  
                                            http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd">  
                        <wfs:Update typeName="SDSDupdate:points">  
                          <wfs:Property>  
                            <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>  
                            <wfs:Value>  
                              <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">  
                                <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">15.453680224345835, 74.25796508789062</gml:coordinates>  
                              </gml:Point>  
                            </wfs:Value>  
                          </wfs:Property>  
                          <ogc:Filter>  
                            <PropertyIsEqualTo>  
                              <PropertyName>pid</PropertyName>  
                              <Literal>cd607b28-6ac5-85d1-bbb1-c880efbce4d9</Literal>  
                            </PropertyIsEqualTo>  
                          </ogc:Filter>  
                        </wfs:Update>  
                      </wfs:Transaction>
```

As suggested by NMS here is the new post to the edited part:
[Geoserver WFST Insert Exception: Error performing insert: Error inserting features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293387/geoserver-wfst-insert-exception-error-performing-insert-error-inserting-featur)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be the problem with GML request your sending.

There should be **no white space after the comma**, that gives you the Parsing error. Here is the corrected snapshot of your request:

```
<gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">  
                                <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">15.453680224345835,74.25796508789062</gml:coordinates>  
                              </gml:Point>
```

Comment: Well @NMS ur awesome, that right !!!

Comment: update is working fine. Now I am facing a new issue while inserting:
`org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Error performing insert: Error inserting features`

Comment: @GeoFresher is the error due to the same request as above?

Comment: No ..that's the different one..

Comment: Any logs or request for your error would be better? Not able to figure it out.

Comment: Here is the insert request: (edited in my question)

Comment: @GeoFresher it seems the edited part doesn't support your question, I would suggest you to create a new post based on that error.