# Geoserver WFST Insert Exception: Error performing insert: Error inserting features

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I am trying an WFST Insert operation as seen below in GeoServer Demos.

```
<wfs:Transaction
      service="WFS"
      version="1.1.0"
      xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
      xmlns:SDSDupdate="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/SDSDupdate"
      xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
      xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs
                          http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/WFS-transaction.xsd
                          http://localhost:8080/geoserver/SDSDupdate/wfs/DescribeFeatureType?typename=SDSDupdate:points">
      <wfs:Insert>
        <SDSDupdate:points>
          <SDSDupdate:pid>cd607b28-6ac5-85d1-bbb1-c880efbce4d8</SDSDupdate:pid>
          <SDSDupdate:class>green</SDSDupdate:class>
          <SDSDupdate:ip>162.XXX.XXX.XXX</SDSDupdate:ip>
          <SDSDupdate:ogr_geometry>
            <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">
              <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">34.67992891939961,135.17650846391916</gml:coordinates>
            </gml:Point>
          </SDSDupdate:ogr_geometry>
        </SDSDupdate:points>
      </wfs:Insert>
    </wfs:Transaction>
```

I get the following error:

> **Error performing insert: Error inserting features**

**EDIT: Full stack trace**

```
   2018-08-20 19:05:59,671 ERROR [geoserver.wfs] - Transaction failed
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: Error performing insert: Error inserting features
    at org.geoserver.wfs.InsertElementHandler.execute(InsertElementHandler.java:218)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.execute(Transaction.java:322)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.Transaction.transaction(Transaction.java:109)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.DefaultWebFeatureService.transaction(DefaultWebFeatureService.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor266.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy91.transaction(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor269.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:867)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:270)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error inserting features
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1785)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.flush(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:128)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.write(JDBCInsertFeatureWriter.java:100)
    at org.geotools.data.InProcessLockingManager$1.write(InProcessLockingManager.java:337)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeature(ContentFeatureStore.java:308)
    at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureStore.addFeatures(ContentFeatureStore.java:259)
    at org.vfny.geoserver.global.GeoServerFeatureStore.addFeatures(GeoServerFeatureStore.java:80)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.InsertElementHandler.execute(InsertElementHandler.java:191)
    ... 106 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for sequence points_id_seq
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2476)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2189)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:300)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:428)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:354)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:301)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:287)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1097)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:1079)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:323)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingStatement.java:323)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insertNonPS(JDBCDataStore.java:1948)
    at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.insert(JDBCDataStore.java:1781)
    ... 113 more
2018-08-20 19:05:59,676 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: transaction
    service = WFS
    version = 1.1.0
    baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
    group[0] = wfs:insert=net.opengis.wfs.impl.InsertElementTypeImpl@20d355d8 (feature: [SimpleFeatureImpl:points=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=6, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: class<class id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=black, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ip<ip id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=162.158.92.164, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: pid<pid id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=cd607b28-6ac5-85d1-bbb1-c880efbce4c8, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: created<created id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=POINT (35.67992891939961 135.17650846391916)]], handle: null, idgen: <unset>, inputFormat: <unset>, srsName: null)
    insert[0]:
        feature[0] = SimpleFeatureImpl:points=[SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: id<id id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=6, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: class<class id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=black, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: ip<ip id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=162.158.92.164, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: pid<pid id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=cd607b28-6ac5-85d1-bbb1-c880efbce4c8, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: created<created id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=null, SimpleFeatureImpl.Attribute: the_geom<the_geom id=fid--4a319acd_16556454987_-7fd1>=POINT (35.67992891939961 135.17650846391916)]
        idgen = GenerateNew
        inputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1
    releaseAction = ALL
2018-08-20 19:05:59,682 INFO [geoserver.servlets] - OutputStream was successfully aborted.
2018-08-20 19:05:59,682 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: Error performing insert: Error inserting features
    at org.geoserver.wfs.response.TransactionResponse.v_1_1(TransactionResponse.java:196)
    at org.geoserver.wfs.response.TransactionResponse.write(TransactionResponse.java:66)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1019)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Permission settings in GeoServer is as seen in the image below:
[image]

It works from backend, (direct insertion) but fails when its being sent through GeoServer.

Comment: does your user have permission to write to the store?

Comment: yes. I did check that part and user has permissions to read and write. The update and delete transaction is working fine.

Comment: @IanTurton u seem to be right with ur permission guess as per the full stack logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied
>   for sequence points_id_seq

So you need to grant access to the sequence to your user

```
GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCE points_id_seq TO youruser;
```

Comment: seems confusing to me. I don't have `points_id_seq` relation or  Have i made some wrong permission settings in geoserver? (Image attached in EDIT)

Comment: @GeoFresher this is n Postgres and has nothing to do with Geoserver. It is a sequence created by you, either directly or when creating a column with the serial type

Comment: your right, I had missed permissions on the sequence on my schema. Its working now.